# google platform.js causes IOS link bug

Tags: javascript, ios, google-api

I'm getting a strange bug on ios 7 (not sure if it exists on earlier versions) where the the google api platform.js renders some links un-clickable. I'm using the youtube subscribe link, which requires platform.js to load for it to function, but causes this bug in ios.

Oddly enough the script fixes another bug that I'm having where links on IOS require two taps/clicks to fire. The first loads the `:hover` state then the second tap will fire the link. (But that's a separate issue).

You can see the bug here: http://dev2014.rab.co.uk/ specifically the links in the footer are affected.

Anyone else seen this?

Thanks

Comment: @keeg I must have but cannot remember what the issue was. Possibly something to do with `event.preventDefault();` maybe?

Comment: Interesting I'll test it out. Thanks